# Problema no header, padding-top está mudando o height do header

Tags: html, css

*{

```
margin: 0;

padding: 0;}
```

.header{

```
background-color: #212343;  
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
text-align: center;
word-spacing: 15px;
font-size: 20px;
padding-top: 15px;
```

}

.header > a{

```
color: white;
```

}

.banner-fundo{

```
width: 100%;
height: 555px;
background-image: url('../imagens/aviao.png');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

O padding altera a altura sim, em resumo a padding é uma margem interna, então soma a altura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se quiser adicionar uma "distancia" fora do box, deve usar o margin, que basicamente, faz o mesmo, porém fora do elemento.

Comment: _O padding altera a altura sim, em resumo a padding é uma margem interna, então soma a altura._ - Isso não é correto, depende do box model utilizado, que é regulado pela propriedade `box-sizing`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing - No caso do seu screenshot você está falando específicamente do elemento estar usando `border-box`, por isso a linha sólida indicada no inspetor